# Pick a number check a db if its there repeat if not store

Tags: mysql, node.js, random

I am trying to write some code for a quiz where the quiz is 5 questions sent to the user (at each attempt to do the quiz) but the questions need to be randomized and not repeated.
The total number of questions we have is 350 which is also the maximum number of questions a user can answer in the quiz.

To solve this issue I am trying to do some code where my server picks a random number between 1 and 350. When that is done it checks a MySQL DB to see if the number is already included in the DB. If the number is in the DB it repeats the process. If the number is not found then it adds it to the DB. Also if the user has answered 350 questions already the code should return a string saying "you have completed the quiz".

The DB has one table called users. Users has a userid(varchar) and question(int). The question is random number being chosen userid is the userid for the player.

I have no idea where to start to write this however my concept as to how ti can work is below, I am asking for some help to solve this.

```
let result = 0;
con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
while (result >= 1)
    {
        let x = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
        con.query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM users where column2 = x", function (err, result, fields) 
        {
            if (err) throw err;
            result = result.length;
        });
    }
var sql = "INSERT INTO users (column1, column2) VALUES ('a string', x)";

});
```

Comment: What happen when all numbers 1 to 5 are already in db?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza then a message will be returned saying you completed the process

Comment: Well your code doesn't show anything about it. Can you elaborate what is the problem you are trying to solve with this function. Right now doesn't seem to be much useful. What is wrong with the code right now? Where you need help?

Comment: The code isnt working regardless of what happens after it inserts all the numbers I need to ensure the numbers are being inserted first. The code is part of a bigger idea for a quiz I want to ensure that questions are not repeated but random questions can be sent to the user.

Comment: Yes but `ISNT WORKING` doesnt tell us much. Is there an error? Wrong behaviour?

Comment: the details of what I am trying to do is there and it isn't working is that it sint doing what I expect it to do there is absolutely no more detail that I can give. the functionality I want is not obtained from the code I wrote so I need guidance as to how to achieve what I want @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza added more detail I hope this helps

Comment: You can do this much efficiently with a modification of Paul code. but you didnt include your tables schema. Just bring a random set of 5 where the question hasnt already be asked.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue of Node.js - But it should be possible to do what you want with a single SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO users (column1, column2) 
SELECT 'a string', numbers.x
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as x UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as x UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as x UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as x UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 as x
) as numbers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE users.column2 = numbers.x
)
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

It should insert a number from a random row in the first subquery, which doesn't already exist in `column2` of the `users` table.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No it would insert nothing.